# Allocating memory to a pointer, pointing another pointer to the same and deleting the second

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

Would a code like that do a proper memory deallocation?

```
int main(){
int *pointerA, *pointerB;

pointerA = new int[15]();
for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
    pointerA[i] = i*2;


pointerB = pointerA;


if (pointerA != NULL)
      pointerA = NULL;

// Some operation here ...
for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
    std::cout << i << " : " << pointerB[i] << std::endl;

if (pointerB != NULL)
    delete [] pointerB;
pointerB = NULL;


return 0;
```

}

I'm creating a pointer using pointerA but deallocation using pointerB. pointerB points to the same location as pointerA.

I think it should deallocate properly but would like to make sure. Is there a way I can efficiently test that? Maybe creating a huge array then checking memory usage???

Thanks

Comment: This behaves exactly like you think it does. But you shouldn't care. Use vectors or unique_ptr or shared_ptr and stop thinking about pointers.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to delete memory allocated by another pointer, which is what you're doing here.

Comment: I suggest learning the language basics to avoid obfuscating your code with entirely pointless stuff. `if(pointerA == NULL) pointerA = NULL;` is perfectly equivalent to `pointerA = NULL;`. Likewise, the `NULL` check before the `delete` is superfluous, `delete` is guaranteed to do nothing with a nullpointer. Especially, since you have been accessing the memory behind `pointerB` *before* you ask whether it is `NULL`; if there were any chance of it being `NULL`, you would already have triggered undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code sample will correctly deallocate all of the memory that was allocated.

If you were to set a breakpoint on the line before `pointerA` is set to `NULL` and compared the memory addresses that `pointerA` and `pointerB` point to, you would see that they point to the same location in memory. Therefore it doesn't matter which variable you use to delete the memory, since the same location in memory would be deleted in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly fine to free memory using the second pointer. You can test thing like this by running something like

```
$ valgrind --log-file=/tmp/memcheck.log --tool=memcheck \
           --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 ./your_tool


$ cat /tmp/memcheck.log
```

You will see errors if you try to delete something that you didn't allocate.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is "usually".  There are two things I'd caution you about.  Be sure that if you use "new" that you also use "delete", or if you use malloc() be sure to use free().  The runtime libraries can use different implementations, where trying to combine "new" and "free()" or "malloc()" and "delete" may lead to leaks.

This can also be a problem if you are dealing with two separately linked libraries, such as you might find with a .DLL and an .EXE, or two .DLLs.  The runtimes that allocate the memory during "new" will be allocating memory in that module's tables, but if the delete takes place in a different module, the "delete" will not be pointing at the same memory allocation table.

In general, I strongly recommend following the pattern of the "allocator" of memory being the same as the "deallocator" of memory.  See [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for a best practice.